# GitHub Desktop won't install on macos Catalina

Tags: macos, github, macos-catalina

Today, I attempted installing GitHub Desktop on my mac and I got a following message:

*"GitHub Desktop" can't be opened because Apple cannot check it for malicious software.* 
*This software needs to be updated. Contact the developer for more information.*

I'm running macOS 10.15. Catalina on MacBook Air 2017, and I guess this has to do something with the new system architecture requirements.

**Question:** Is anyone else facing the same or similar problem and, if yes, is there any information when will the GitHub team update the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reconfigure Gatekeeper to allow apps from anywhere to be opened. This is not recommended but is possible. To do this, run this command in Terminal.

```
sudo spctl --master-disable
```

GitHub Desktop should open after running this.

Answer (score 3):

For as long as this is an issue, you can right click the application and click "Open", then when prompted click "Open" again. This will open the application, even though the message says "can't be opened".

Comment: opened then .. closed

Answer (score 2):

This message means that the app was not being notarized by Apple. There is nothing you can do about it. GutHub has do submit the app for notarization.
You should probably send a support request to GitHub.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing. Just wanted to check for with more people. Thank you.